# Two transparent gateway using squid return 403

Tags: squid, gateway, transparent-proxy

I have two linux gateway using squid as transparent proxy. When I using them individually, everything is fine. But when I using them in the same network, every request from browser will return 403.

The network topological structure like this:

Client -> | Transparent gateway A -> Transparent gateway B | -> Internet

```
        A:172.16.0.1       B:10.190.90.1
```

1. If gateway A or gateway B not exists, everything is fine.
2. If they both exist, client browser always get 403.

iptables setting is:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

EDIT:

both gateways' squid.conf are:

> acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
>
> acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
>
> acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
>
> acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
>
> acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged)
>
> acl SSL_ports port 443
>
> acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
>
> acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
>
> acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
>
> acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
>
> acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
>
> acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
>
> acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
>
> acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
>
> acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
>
> acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
>
> acl CONNECT method CONNECT
>
> http_access deny !Safe_ports
>
> http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
>
> http_access allow localhost manager
>
> http_access deny manager
>
> http_access allow localnet
>
> http_access allow localhost
>
> http_access deny all
>
> http_port 3128 intercept
>
> http_port 3129

Comment: What are ACLs on both squid setup ?

Comment: @XavierLucas Please read the edited part.

Comment: Check the logs to see which proxy actually returns the 403, and try to `curl` a website from gateway A and see if that works.

Comment: @AndréDaniel both proxy return 403, and curl a website from gateway A works normally.